# Scrollable image out of bound

Tags: image, python-2.7, tkinter, text, scrollable

When I scroll the text widget, the images get out of bound. There is a code which solve my problem?

I am using Tkinter's text widget.

```py
def chat():       
        self.t = Text(self.root, borderwidth=4, width=72, height=15, font=("david",14))
        self.t.place(x=10, y=200)
        self.t.config(state=DISABLED)

def add_image(self, path,name):
        image = Image.open(path)
        photoImg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image.resize((170, 170)))
        icon_size = Label(self.root)
        icon_size.image = photoImg  
        icon_size.configure(image=photoImg)
        icon_size.pack(side=LEFT)
        self.t.config(state=NORMAL)
        self.t.insert(END, name + ": ")
        self.t.window_create(END, window=icon_size) 
        self.t.insert(END, '\n')
        self.t.config(state=DISABLED)
```

Comment: Can you provide a complete and executable example that shows the problem you are having? The code you have shared isn't complete enough to allow anyone to replicate your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example that might be helpful but it is based on many assumptions given that you haven't provided a full code example. It is also written for Python 3 not 2.7 since the Python Software Foundation do not recommend writing new code in 2.7.

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.scrolledtext as tkst

root = Tk()
t = tkst.ScrolledText(root,borderwidth=4,width=72,height=15)
t.grid()
t.config(state=DISABLED)

names = ['bill','allan','steve','chloe','annabelle','louise','stephanie']
images = []
icons = []

for name in names:
    img = PhotoImage(file='icon.gif')
    icon = Label(root)
    icon.image = img
    icon.configure(image=img)

    t.config(state=NORMAL)
    t.insert(END, name+":")
    t.window_create(END,window=icon)
    t.insert(END, "\n")

    images.append(img)
    icons.append(icon)

root.mainloop()
```

Note that I keep the images stored in a list so that they are retained. I've also used the tkinter scrolled text widget to add a scroll bar to the text widget.